# Uart Module and op

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, verilog, fpga

I want to light leds respectively in fpga (Nexys 2 ) by using Verilog, but I didn't synchronize between bluetooth (hc-06) and fpga. For example: I send 255 (1111 1111) from my phone and light led 4. It should have lit all 8 leds.

I doubt that the issue is that I didn't set the baud rate correctly (bluetooth baudrate is default 9600).

My Verilog code is posted below.

Baud rate part :

```
    module baud_rate_gen(input wire clk_50m,
         output wire rxclk_en,
         output wire txclk_en);

parameter RX_ACC_MAX = 50000000 / (9600 * 10);
parameter TX_ACC_MAX = 50000000 / 9600;
parameter RX_ACC_WIDTH = 9;//$clog2(RX_ACC_MAX);
parameter TX_ACC_WIDTH = 8;//$clog2(TX_ACC_MAX);
reg [RX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0] rx_acc = 0;
reg [TX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0] tx_acc = 0;

assign rxclk_en = (rx_acc == 5'd0);
assign txclk_en = (tx_acc == 9'd0);

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
if (rx_acc == RX_ACC_MAX[RX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0])
    rx_acc <= 0;
else
    rx_acc <= rx_acc + 5'b1;
end

always @(posedge clk_50m) begin
if (tx_acc == TX_ACC_MAX[TX_ACC_WIDTH - 1:0])
    tx_acc <= 0;
else
    tx_acc <= tx_acc + 9'b1;
end

endmodule
```

Transmitter and receiver part is copied from

https://github.com/jamieiles/uart/blob/master/receiver.v
https://github.com/jamieiles/uart/blob/master/transmitter.v

Part of ucf file:

```
NET "dout<0>"  LOC = "J14"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L14N_1/A3/RHCLK7, Type = RHCLK/DUAL, Sch name = JD10/LD0
NET "dout<1>"  LOC = "J15"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L14P_1/A4/RHCLK6, Type = RHCLK/DUAL, Sch name = JD9/LD1
NET "dout<2>"  LOC = "K15"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L12P_1/A8/RHCLK2, Type = RHCLK/DUAL, Sch name = JD8/LD2
NET "dout<3>"  LOC = "K14"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L12N_1/A7/RHCLK3/TRDY1, Type = RHCLK/DUAL, Sch name = JD7/LD3
NET "dout<4>"  LOC = "E17"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO, Type = I/O, Sch name = LD4? s3e500 only
NET "dout<5>"  LOC = "P15"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO, Type = I/O, Sch name = LD5? s3e500 only
NET "dout<6>"  LOC = "F4";  # Bank = 3, Pin name = IO, Type = I/O, Sch name = LD6? s3e500 only
NET "dout<7>"  LOC = "R4";  # Bank = 3, Pin name = IO/VREF_3, Type = VREF, Sch name = LD7? s3e500 only
```

Pin connectors part:

```
NET "tX" LOC = "L17"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L10N_1/VREF_1, Type = VREF, Sch name = JA3
NET "rx" LOC = "M15"; # Bank = 1, Pin name = IO_L07P_1, Type = I/O, Sch name = JA4
```

uart_top module:

```
module uart(input wire [7:0] din,
    input wire wr_en,
    input wire clk_50m,
    output wire tx,
    output wire tx_busy,
    input wire rx,
    output wire rdy,
    input wire rdy_clr,
    output wire [7:0] dout,
     output tX,
     input reset);

wire rxclk_en, txclk_en;


baud_rate_gen uart_baud(.clk_50m(clk_50m),
        .rxclk_en(rxclk_en),
        .txclk_en(txclk_en));
transmitter uart_tx(.din(din),
        .wr_en(wr_en),
        .clk_50m(clk_50m),
        .clken(txclk_en),
        .tx(tx),
        .tx_busy(tx_busy));
receiver uart_rx(.rx(rx),
     .rdy(rdy),
     .rdy_clr(rdy_clr),
     .clk_50m(clk_50m),
     .clken(rxclk_en),
     .data(dout));

     assign tX = 1;

 endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

First think I noticed is that the receiver has `==15` which suggest a 16x oversampling clock. Looking in github comment section confirms this.

Your baud rate code uses `50000000 / (9600 * 10);` which is a 10x baud rate clock, not 16.

In your baud rate code and in git hub UART code there is extensive use of initialized variables. There are many cases where that will not work. The correct way is to use a reset.

I only glanced at the github receiver code but it is very, very sloppy:

- No header at the top of the file explaining what it is or does.
- Does not have a reset
- Has no synchronizer. UART data arrives asynchronous to the clock and needs to be synchronized!
- rdy written in two places. Here it means a rdy_clr arriving at the same time as the data byte data losses the data byte.
- No overflow detection.
- Stop state does not check for bit high. This makes that an unconnected line (always low) is seen as a bit stream of all zeros.

Minor point:  Assembling receiving byte is done with a de-multiplexer. `scratch[bitpos[2:0]]` a lot of slow logic for what you can do with a shift register.